# How to solve logits and labels must have the same shape ((64, 20, 1440) vs (64, 2))

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, neural-network, lstm

i'm newbie in machine learning, and i try to run lstm multi layers with keras. here's my code:

```
from keras.layers import Embedding
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Embedding, Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM

X_train = pad_sequences(sequences_train)
X_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test,maxlen=X_train.shape[1])
y_train = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels[train_data.index]))
y_test = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels[test_data.index]))

embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 128

sequence_length = X_train.shape[1]
inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
embedding = embedding_layer(inputs)
reshape = Reshape((sequence_length,EMBEDDING_DIM,1))(embedding)
adam = Adam(lr=1e-1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim = len(word_index)+1, output_dim = EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length = sequence_length, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(((lstm_out)), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(labels), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle = True)

print(model.summary())
```

and some errors appear

```
File "E:\Codes\LSTM_multi_Layers.py", line 31, in <module>
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle = True)

ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((64, 20, 1440) vs (64, 2))
```

What does it mean? and what should be changed from my code? can somebody help me, please.